# Spring Declarative Transaction Advice pointcut error

Tags: java, spring, transactionmanager

I am trying to implement spring's transaction management using datasaourceTransactionManager. Here is my application-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd" >

    <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />    

   <bean   id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"
    p:username="hr"
    p:password="********" />


   <bean id="datasourceTransactionManager"
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
         p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"   />

   <bean id="daoClass"
         class="com.dao.DaoClass"
         p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"
         p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
         /> 

           <tx:advice id="transactionAdvice" transaction-manager="datasourceTransactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="enterPublisher"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>

        <aop:pointcut id="transactionPointcut" expression="execution(* com.dao.DaoClass.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="transactionAdvice" pointcut="transactionPointcut"/>

    </aop:config>

   <bean id="sessionFactory"
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
         p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
         p:configLocation="/configs/hibernate.cfg.xml">
       <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <map>
               <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
               <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
           </map>
       </property>
   </bean>
```

However upon starting the application i am receiving the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [configs/appContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting '(' at character position 0
transactionPointcut
^

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at springhibernate.SpringHibernate.main(SpringHibernate.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting '(' at character position 0
transactionPointcut
^

at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.resolvePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:316)
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:294)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:212)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:199)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:188)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:168)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:208)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:262)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:294)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:372)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
... 9 more
Java Result: 1
```

I can't seem to find the issue with the pointcut expression. Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pointcut-ref` instead of the `pointcut` attribute in your `aop:advisor`.